# How to sort turtles by their strength in netlogo

Tags: sorting, netlogo

guys any one have implementation of  bubble sort in netlogo help because i want to sort turtles by their strength and i have not much knowledge about that language

```
turtles-own[strength]

to setup
ca
create-turtles num-turtle [
  set strength random 100
  fd 5
  set size 2
  set label strength
]
ask turtles [show sort [strength] of turtles ]

end

to bubblesort
  set liste [strength] of turtles
  if (turtle 0 [strength]) >= (turtle 1 [strength] ) ) [set size 5 ]
end
```

Comment: Please don't spam tags. Also, we are not a coding service. If you need to solve an issue, post the code you tried and tell us what didn't work, why, what was the expected behaviour and what's happening instead. If you want us to write code for you, that won't happen.

Comment: Why do you have javascript and java tagged... They are not the same!

Comment: sorry for that i was beginner

Answer (score 0):

take a look on [sort-on](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.0/docs/dictionary.html#sort-on). It work for me

```
turtles-own[strength]

to setup
ca
create-turtles num-turtle [
  set strength random 100
  fd 5
  set size 2
  set label strength
]
show sort-on [strength] turtles

end
```

the result in console is a list

```
observer: [(turtle 1) (turtle 2) (turtle 7) (turtle 8) (turtle 5) (turtle 0) (turtle 6) (turtle 3) (turtle 9) (turtle 4)]
```

Comment: brother but i wanna sort turtles at turtle level not on observer level

Comment: ? `ask turtles[
  show sort-on [strength] turtles
]`

Comment: brother this is nice but i wanna sort without using built in function like sort-on sort-by stuff like that